# PowerShell Core 7 vs. Windows Powershell 5.1 - Compare-Object distinct results

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compare 2 directories with compare-object using PowerShell Core 7.0.
After some tries, I was getting strange results and so I tried to use the same code in Windows Powershell 5.1.
So, when I use Powershell Core 7.0 these are the results:

```
    PS C:\> $folderLeft = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Tests'
    PS C:\> $folderRight = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Tests2'
    PS C:\> Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $folderLeft -DifferenceObject $folderRight

InputObject               SideIndicator
-----------               -------------
C:\Tests2\UTILS           =>
C:\Tests2\test - copy.txt =>
C:\Tests2\test.txt        =>
C:\Tests\UTILS            <=
C:\Tests\test.txt         <=
```

When I use WindowsPowerShell 5.1:

```
PS C:\> $folderLeft = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Tests'
PS C:\> $folderRight = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Tests2'
PS C:\> Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $folderLeft -DifferenceObject $folderRight

InputObject     SideIndicator
-----------     -------------
test - copy.txt =>
```

I get the desired results in WindowsPowerShell 5.1.

Anyone knows if there's a way to solve this in PowerShell Core?

Comment: `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $folderLeft.Name -DifferenceObject $folderRight.Name` might do the trick

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, that, indeed, did the trick! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you why it's happening.  In ps 7 the file and dir objects convert to strings with the fullname, but in ps 5 they convert only to the name itself.  Usually compare-object will convert the objects to strings and sort them first, with some rare exceptions like datetime's that support -gt/-lt.  It has to be able to sort the lists to work.

```
$folderLeft[0].tostring()   # ps 7
C:\Tests\UTILS

$folderLeft[0].tostring()   # ps 5
UTILS

$folderleft[0] -gt $folderleft[1]
Cannot compare "utils" because it is not IComparable.
At line:1 char:1
+ $folderleft[0] -gt $folderleft[1]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotIcomparable
```

You can pick the properties to compare by and that will work in ps7.  It won't check all the properties automatically.

```
Compare-Object $folderLeft $folderRight -property name

name            SideIndicator
----            -------------
test - copy.txt =>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit Tricky. If you want to have a full and shipshaped compare including subdirectories, you will need to build a substring and then do the compare on it:

```
$folderLeft = 'C:\Tests'
$folderLeftFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path folderLeft  | Sort-Object
$folderLeftFiles | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name compare -Value 'init'
$folderLeftFiles | ForEach-Object {$_.compare= ($_.FullName.Substring(($folderLeft.Length+1),($_.FullName.Length- ($folderLeft.Length+1))))} 

<#
do the same for folderRight
#>
 $difference = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $folderLeftFiles.('compare') -DifferenceObject $folderRightFiles.('compare')
```

In particular with subfolders, other solutions might not give you the correct result.

This code works in v5 and v7 of powershell

Comment: You're missing a $ before folderleft in line two.  Or you can add an IComparable CompareTo() method to each object.